# How to fix decimal invalid operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

```
decimal.getcontext().prec = 14
array = [decimal.Decimal('-0.24246792859937'), decimal.Decimal('-0.24246793714039')]  
f = lambda a: (a[0]**decimal.Decimal('1.05000000000000')) + (a[1]**decimal.Decimal('1.05000000000000'))  
print(f(array))
```

And I will give the error

```
    f = lambda a: (a[0]**decimal.Decimal('1.05000000000000')) + (a[1]**decimal.Decimal('1.05000000000000'))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

How to fix this?

Comment: FWIW, the [mcve] for the offending operations are just ``decimal.Decimal('-0.24246793714039')**decimal.Decimal('1.05')`` and ``decimal.Decimal('-0.24246792859937')**decimal.Decimal('1.05')``. In fact, ``decimal.Decimal('-0.2')**decimal.Decimal('1.05')`` is sufficient to repro.

Comment: The problem is that this part of this example breaks my gradient descent code for such conditional function. It is necessary to understand how to solve the problem with accuracy

Comment: What result do you expect for the individual operation? Your formula gives a [complex number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-0.2%29**1.05), not a decimal/rational number. ``decimal.Decimal`` cannot represent the result.

Comment: Ahhhh. I see. Thank you, it was stupid to ask such a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the numbers are complex